# How can I call a SQL Tabular function multiple times in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, function, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am writing a function that checks whether there are DQ issue in a column of a table. For example, if there are nulls when nulls aren't permitted.

At the moment the function is called like this:

```
 SELECT * FROM TABLE(DQ_IS_NULL('TABLE_1','COLUMN_1'));
```

I would like to enable the user to call the function multiple times for multiple columns at the same time for x amount of columns. e.g

```
 SELECT * FROM TABLE(DQ_IS_NULL('TABLE_1','COLUMN_1','TABLE_1','COLUMN_2'))
```

I am writing this in Snowflake and it needs to be in SQL. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the table function signature is static then the most appropriate way(without rewriting it) would be using UNION ALL:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(DQ_IS_NULL('TABLE_1','COLUMN_1'))
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TABLE(DQ_IS_NULL('TABLE_1','COLUMN_2'))
```

Comment: Thanks. I would be happy to rewrite it if needed. How would I make my function more dynamic?

Comment: @AlexMarkides It is hard to tell without actual seeing the code but you could think about column list as ARRAY/VARIANT type i.e. `TABLE(DQ_IS_NULL('TABLE_1',['COLUMN_1', 'COLUMN2']))`